# .net sqlclient connection local binding to other IP (non default)

Tags: c#, .net, sqlclient

I have a server with multiples IP's, for example, the default is 10.1.1.2 and a seconday is 192.168.1.2

I must connect to remote SQL Server but usign the 192.168.1.2.

How can I set the local IP in the SqlClient Connection?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set a connection string in your properties:

```
Data Source=192.168.1.2;Initial Catalog=<databaseName>;uid=<userName>;pwd=<password>
```

Comment: Data Source is the remote IP (the ip to connect TO, not FROM). I need to set the IP from where the connection will be made. This only will apply if computer client has multiples IPs

Comment: Right didn't understand the question fully, then the answer depends on your network infrastructure, 192.168.1.2 is a LAN IP address if the remote server is an external one then I'm pretty sure that it isn't possibly to do what you want without a VPN